# How to access to the prop assigned component in enzyme

Tags: material-ui, jestjs, enzyme

This is my component:

```
const Cmp = (props) => (
  <List>
    <ListItem primaryText='test' leftCheckbox={<Checkbox onCheck={props.onCheck} />} />
  </List>
);
```

I want to test checking of the checkbox. Here is my test:

```
it('test', (done) => {
  const handleCheck = () => {
    done();
  }

  const wrapper = shallow(<Cmp onCheck={handleCheck} />);
  wrapper.find('the checkbox').simulate('check');
});
```

How can I find the checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the `ListItem` element then get the `prop` and call `simulate` on it:

```
it('test', (done) => {
  const handleCheck = () => {
    done();
  }

  const wrapper = shallow(<Cmp onCheck={handleCheck} />);
  const checkBox = shallow(wrapper.find('ListItem').first().prop('leftCheckbox')())
  checkbox.simulate('check');
});
```

Comment: I tried. Does not work with error `TypeError: checkbox.simulate is not a function`

Comment: can you log `checkBox`, I assume it was not rendered yet, so maybe you have to write it like this `shallow(checkBox).simulate('check')`